# Disable LED on 8192cu Edimax dongle, kernel drivers

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to disable the LED light on an EDIMAX 8192cu dongle, raspberry pi2, running ArchLinux, kernel 3.18.14-1-ARCH.

Previously, I compiled the driver from the chip set manufacturer and patched it, however I'd like to stick with the kernel driver now. It is stable, and doesn't require dkms, which is an issue as the only way to access this box is via ssh over wifi.

Looking for an echo command to toggle it ideally. This would allow me to streamline it with a script I have to turn off the LEDs for the on-board pi's leds.

Comment: Might be relevant; http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40560/disable-led-for-edimax-ew-7811/41059#41059 I have a sym-link and switch between the original and patch drivers via a cmd.